# Creating Matrix of Buttons in Android dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create matrix of buttons in Android dynamically for some m rows and n columns. It should be aligned in matrix form(table form). Plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a gridlayout

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: right... so if u r targeting lower versions gridview  can be an option

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gridlayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) and add buttons dynamically based on positions in the getView method of the custom adapter.